# Change hover color on wordpress website for specific page and not for the main menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a website using a uncode theme on WordPress. I am trying to change the on hover color on the blog page/shop page specifically because it's built differently from the other pages.

Presently on hover it goes white, with white background...

[www.beautinda.de](http://www.beautinda.de)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which part of the page you want to change? Btw it should be quite easy, Wordpress attach to the html body element a lot of classes by default, and theme/plugins can add more. In those classes you will for sure find one that will hit only the blog/shop page.

After you identified which are those two classes it's just a matter of CSS using as starting selector:

```
body.[page-specific-class] .my-element:hover{ color: red; }
```

Giving a first look you could use `post-type-archive-product` as selector for the shop page and `page-id-4302` for the blog page. Be careful that if you translate the blog page the ID will change so you may need to add another one for the translated page

Comment: I think you might be better off looking for a class which contains woocommerce rather than rely on the Wordpress post number which can change for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: I gree with you @AHaworth but unfortunatly the blog page isn't managed by woocommerce so it doesn't have any wc specific class

Comment: Ah, I thought it was the shop page you wanted to alter?

Comment: He says in the question "... hover color on the blog page/shop page specifically ..." so i supposed both of them ^^